# Validate password+salt with another salt

Tags: encoding, cryptography, authorization

I'm storing the user's credentials in a database with the encoded password: sha1(pw + salt) and the salt.
When I'm trying to login the user from a client app I do the same thing only with a different salt value, so I send the sha1(pw + another_salt) and another_salt for authorization.

The question is that what further modification should be done to the received encoded password to be able to check against the stored value.

Comment: Another note: Don't use a fast hash like SHA-1 (or SHA-2) for password hashing, use a slow hash. See [What makes a hash function good for password hashing?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24/what-makes-a-hash-function-good-for-password-hashing) for details.

Comment: To emphasize Paŭlo's point: Any decent authentication algorithm uses tens of thousands of iterations of a hash algorithm, in order to make dictionary attacks too expensive computationally. I would strongly encourage you to use a third-party library to manage your password authentication, like a `bcrypt` implementation. When you understand how it works, and why it does everything that it does, you can start thinking about writing your own—though by that time, hopefully you'll have realized you still don't have the necessary expertise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you send something from client it doesn't matter if it's hashed password or just string. And if it's content generated by client (i.e. you generate salt on client, not on server) - attacker could as well just send your string. So if it's not secured connection, then you add additional work which doesn't help.

To allow checking passwords on server with another salt, you need to store original password in clear text.

That's the whole point of storing hashes instead of passwords in database is to not allow guessing them from hash only. And if you salt them additionally, then you need to use the same salt (it's public, as it's stored in database in clear text, but it's now part of original password). What you ask is something like this:

> Haw to login on user (whose password is "secure password" + "hard" => sha1("secure passwordhard")) sending something + "soft" (and then test with sha1(something + "soft")) instead.

If you really need this app to work, just send user's password in cleartext from client app, but over secured connection.

Comment: "To allow checking passwords on server with another salt, you need to store original password in clear text." - Please don't give that kind of advice. Take a look at SRP for a system which stores hased passwords, with a per invocation salt to thwart replays and other miscreant behavior.

Comment: @noloader I haven't heard of it before, thanks! BUT in SRP (if I understand correctly) you encrypt you password with public key and decrypt with private key on server - that's what I wrote "just send user's password in cleartext from client app, but over **secured connection**", where secured connection can be public-private encryption or SSL or whatever you have at your hand. SRP doesn't allow you to hash user's password with different random salt and send generated SHA1, and then compute another hash on server with original salt.